# Using .png files instead of using .ico files in windows programs

Tags: png, icons

hi I have a collection of nice .png files....
meanwhile, I'm developing a win-based software and need some .ico files as icons for toolbar buttons and ....

Is there any way to use .png file as an icon ? or what?

Thank you

Comment: What language/platform?  What specific UI control?

Answer (score 9):

As a workaround you can use IrfanView to convert your *.png file to *.ico file (or any other image to ico) & use it.

http://www.irfanview.com/main_download_engl.htm

Answer (score 3):

You can simply convert the images to ico files online [Ico Convert](https://icoconvert.com/).

Comment: Gotta love the fact the Windows is still the only major desktop OS out there that doesn't support image files for icons. Linux has it, MacOS has it...For a long time...

Answer (score 2):

If you are using .NET this is not a real problem for you, because afaik PNG support is already build in. You are probably talking about native C/C++ development with GDI/win32?

To my knowledge you will not accomplish this by simply using GDI. There are a couple of options where you can set ONE color as transparent then load a simple BMP/JPEG and do some BITMAP tricks however using ICO/GIF will be far easier for this.

What you are probably looking for is a working GDI+ example which will use a PNG with alpha channel? This is just an excerpt and I left out the whole mess loading external functions from a DLL part, but maybe this will help you:

```c++
static GpImage *background = NULL;

GDIPLOADIMAGEFROMSTREAM GdipLoadImageFromStream;
GDIPLUSSTARTUP          GdiplusStartup; 
GDIPPLUSSHUTDOWN        GdiplusShutdown;
GDIPCREATEFROMHDC       GdipCreateFromHDC;
GDIPDELETEGRAPHICS      GdipDeleteGraphics;
GDIPDRAWIMAGEI          GdipDrawImageI;
GDIPDRAWIMAGERECTI      GdipDrawImageRectI;
GDIPLUS_STARTUP_INPUT   GdiplusStartupInput; 

void LoadPNG(GpImage **image, int resource, HMODULE hInstance)
{
  HRSRC     resrc;
  LPSTREAM  lpstr;
  HGLOBAL   hPng;
  LPVOID    fByte; 
  GpImage *img  = NULL;

  resrc = FindResource(GetModuleHandle(NULL), MAKEINTRESOURCE(resource), TEXT("PNG"));
  hPng  = LoadResource(GetModuleHandle(NULL), resrc);
  fByte = LockResource(hPng);
  lpstr = SHCreateMemStream(fByte, 200000); 
  GdipLoadImageFromStream(lpstr, &img); 
  *image = img;
}

void CreateBack(HWND hWnd)
{
  HDC  memDC = NULL;      
  HDC  hdc   = NULL; 
  RECT rect;

  DeleteObject(curBack);
  GetClientRect(hWnd, &rect);
  hdc = GetDC(hWnd); 

  memDC   = CreateCompatibleDC(hdc); 
  curBack = CreateCompatibleBitmap(hdc, rect.right, 44);   
  SelectObject(memDC, curBack); 

  /* gdiplus - background*/ {
    int e = 0;
    GpGraphics *g;  
    GdipCreateFromHDC(memDC, &g); 
    GdipDrawImageRectI(g, background,  e, 0, 971, 44);
    GdipDeleteGraphics(g);  
  }

  DeleteObject(memDC);  
  ReleaseDC(hWnd, hdc);  
}
```

Just a quick note: This GDI+ stuff is really CPU/memory intensive for a couple of reasons. Although fun I did abandoned this approach in favor of gdi and simple BMPs.

Comment: One thing I left out, to get this working you need to switch to owner drawn buttons in your toolbar... Only worth it in my opinion if you have a changing or multicolored background.

Answer (score 0):

If you're loading the images from a resource file, then no, you can't use PNGs, you have to use ICOs.  Fortunately, there are a number of tools that can convert PNGs into ICOs, including [ImageMagick](http://imagemagick.org) (great for automation), and MSPaint as a lowest common denominator.

If you're loading image files at runtime, then you can load any type of image format you want (e.g. use [libpng](http://libpng.org/pub/png/libpng.html) for loading PNGs), but you still have to convert them to icons internally before you can do interesting things with them, such as setting them as a window's icon.  Once you've decoded the image data, it's not terribly difficult to convert it to the proper format, but it's not trivial, it just involves a lot of data mangling and strange structs and function calls from the Win32 API.

Comment: Just store your PNGs as RCDATA resources. You might have to change some loading code, though.